# How linux kernel distinguish connected socket and listening socket?

Tags: linux, sockets

For instance, a tcp server is listening address 10.10.10.1:80. And client 10.10.10.2:555 connect in. Server accept() will create a new connected socket which is identified by (10.10.10.1:80,10.10.10.2:555,tcp). And server create a thread for connected socket and continue to listen socket.
when the client has new data to server, My question is how kernel distinguish the listen socket and connected socket? (of course they have different filehands, but how kernel get the right socket via the target address?) How kernel know this coming data will be handover to APP via connected socket, not the listen socket? Not sure I get my question clear.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to. The incoming segment is addressed to a local IP:port and has a source address of another IP:port. All it has to do is find a socket with that local IP:port and that remote IP:port. The listening socket won't have a remote IP:port at all, and sockets with that local IP:port that are connected to other peers will have a different remote IP:port.

Comment: So the listening socket identified with (local ip:port, null remote addr), while the created connected socket identified with (local ip:port, remote ip:port). kernel could find correct socket using the ip/udp headers. am i right?